# I can't start any VMs on Synology Nas 920+ Virtualization Manager

Tags: synology, dsm

I was having trouble starting any VM on the Virtualization manager on my Synology 920+ with DSM version DSM 7.2-64570 Update 1. Nothing worked. I was trying all the Ubuntu's mainly server, but desktop too. I even tried Lubuntu.

They would all stop about 3 seconds into the boot. I'll post my solution as an answer below, if possible.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A Synology DSN920+ could easily run in a small business environment, I don't think this is irrelevant.

Comment: It is at home, but it is also for my business, https://digiroth.com/

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to set the video driver to "vga" and not "vmvga", after trying nearly anything. This should be added to the docs, IMO.